# Filter App Distribution by Google Play Service Version

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

My question is simple. Is it possible to serve/distribute an android application to only devices with Google Play Services version x or higher?

I checked distribution filters page but nothing mentioned about Google Play Services there. I kept my hope and came here.

Is there anybody with certain information?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think so, because it does not make much sense. If your app require certain version and user got older, then he shall be asked to upgrade his copy of Google Play Services, so there's in fact no point of not distributing your app to such users (they may simply not be aware of the new version of Google Play Services (or even of existence of creature like Google Play Services at all)

Your app shall call `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()` and one of return codes you can get returned is `ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED` which basically covers case you described. And for that return code you do only:

```
if( GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError( errorCode ) ) {
    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, null, requestCode)
}
```

and let utils do the rest.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, i am aware of this possibility, some users may react negatively when you pop a dialog to install another software which is sized at tens of megabytes. Especially if your core feature depends on Google Play Services and if you show this dialog to the user for the first time the user opens your app i think its a really bad experience which can result in negative feedback and user rating.

Comment: then educate your users. you can either ask them to update or quit your app - no other choices really. or stick to old version of google play while building your app